# Getting week number off a date in MS SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to create an sql statement that selects the week number (NOT the day of week - or the day number in a week). I'm creating a view to select this extra information along with a couple of other fields and thus can not use a stored procedure. I'm aware that it's possible to create a UDF to do the trick, but if at all possible i'd rather only have to add a view to this database, than both a view and a function.

Any ideas? Also where i come from, the week starts monday and week 1 is the first week of the year with atleast 4 days.

#### Related:

> [How do I calculate the week number given a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274861/how-do-i-calculate-the-week-number-given-a-date)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Be aware that there are differences in what is regarded the correct week number, depending on the culture. Week numbers depend on a couple of assumptions that differ from country to country, see [Wikipedia article on the matter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_number). There is an [ISO standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) (ISO 8601) that applies to week numbers.

The SQL server integrated `DATEPART()` function does not necessarily do The Right Thing. SQL Server assumes day 1 of week 1 would be January 1, for many applications that's wrong.

Calculating week numbers correctly is non-trivial, and different implementations can be found on the web. For example, there's an UDF that calculates the [ISO week numbers from 1930-2030](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=60510), being one among many others. You'll have to check what works for you.

This one is from [Books Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms186755.aspx#sectionToggle8) (though you probably want to use [the one from Jonas Lincoln's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/348945/18771), the BOL version seems to be incorrect):

```
CREATE FUNCTION ISOweek  (@DATE DATETIME)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @ISOweek INT
   SET @ISOweek = DATEPART(wk,@DATE) 
                  +1 
                  -DATEPART(wk,CAST(DATEPART(yy,@DATE) AS CHAR(4))+'0104')
   -- Special cases: Jan 1-3 may belong to the previous year
   IF (@ISOweek=0)
      SET @ISOweek = dbo.ISOweek(CAST(DATEPART(yy,@DATE) - 1
                     AS CHAR(4))+'12'+ CAST(24+DATEPART(DAY,@DATE) AS CHAR(2)))+1
   -- Special case: Dec 29-31 may belong to the next year
   IF ((DATEPART(mm,@DATE)=12) AND
      ((DATEPART(dd,@DATE)-DATEPART(dw,@DATE))>= 28))
      SET @ISOweek=1
   RETURN(@ISOweek)
END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks - i like the explicit information about the week numbers apart from the UDF - i think i'll solve it by creating a table with the weeknumbers (or first day of week 1) that i can do simple logic on in my view. The bad part is getting the extra table - but i think it beats a hard-to-read UDF ;)

Comment: But if you would check if the UDF does it - it will be faster than an extra table (if that matters for you), and you would not have to read it very often either. ;-) As I said, there are other implementations out there if you don't like/cannot use this one.

Comment: I would think calling this udf would take longer than a join in an indexed date/week table? I could be wrong, but focus on this task is keeping complexity low (everybody knows how to do an inner join, but not everyone would understand this udf). Thanks for bringing it up - i might have to test it ;)

Comment: Since the UDF is just doing basic math with no IO *at all*, it will be faster than any join. And calling/using it is as simple as calling a normal function ("SELECT dbo.ISOweek(MyDateTime)"), you might even add it to the master DB to have it available on the whole server.

Comment: This is a very long syntax, the logic can be written in just 2 lines

Comment: Tomalak i did, however i am not going to post it on a question that is 3 year old

Comment: @tclausen.dk Then why did you bother to comment?

Comment: THis may sound silly, but i saw alot of articles about it, and they were ALL spagetti code. So I am considering eather to go for the selflearner badge, and/or write an article about it. If i post the solution on a 3 year old question, there will be nothing new about my article, and the answer will go into oblivion and I will not recieve any recognition (I already tried that, answering a 1 year old question with 0 answers).

Comment: Posted this question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330711/isoweek-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: Ever heard of DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,@DATE) ?

Comment: @Quandary yes I have, but sql-server 2005 has not

Comment: I tried this and it DID NOT calculate the correct ISO week numbers. This does: RETURN (datepart(DY, datediff(d, 0, @DATE) / 7 * 7 + 3)+6) / 7

Comment: @Kleky Your fault. You just copied the code and did not read the text in the answer.

Comment: Well the function either returns ISO week number or not - lets not be cryptic about it

Comment: @Kleky You did still not read the text in my answer. Go read it now. It's not about being cryptic at all, but if you criticize me then do it for a mistake that I made.

Answer (score 18):

You need the ISO week. From http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=60510, here's an implementation:

```
drop function dbo.F_ISO_WEEK_OF_YEAR
go
create function dbo.F_ISO_WEEK_OF_YEAR
    (
    @Date   datetime
    )
returns     int
as
/*
Function F_ISO_WEEK_OF_YEAR returns the
ISO 8601 week of the year for the date passed.
*/
begin

declare @WeekOfYear     int

select
    -- Compute week of year as (days since start of year/7)+1
    -- Division by 7 gives whole weeks since start of year.
    -- Adding 1 starts week number at 1, instead of zero.
    @WeekOfYear =
    (datediff(dd,
    -- Case finds start of year
    case
    when    NextYrStart <= @date
    then    NextYrStart
    when    CurrYrStart <= @date
    then    CurrYrStart
    else    PriorYrStart
    end,@date)/7)+1
from
    (
    select
        -- First day of first week of prior year
        PriorYrStart =
        dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,-53690,dateadd(yy,-1,aa.Jan4))/7)*7,-53690),
        -- First day of first week of current year
        CurrYrStart =
        dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,-53690,aa.Jan4)/7)*7,-53690),
        -- First day of first week of next year
        NextYrStart =
        dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,-53690,dateadd(yy,1,aa.Jan4))/7)*7,-53690)
    from
        (
        select
            --Find Jan 4 for the year of the input date
            Jan4    = 
            dateadd(dd,3,dateadd(yy,datediff(yy,0,@date),0))
        ) aa
    ) a

return @WeekOfYear

end
go
```

Comment: Thanks, just needed this today. It's more correct than the accepted answer.

Comment: Ever heard of DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,@DATE) ?

Comment: @Quandary He was looking for a solution for SQL Server 2005, which does not support ISO_WEEK.

Comment: For me this gave better result than answer from Tomalak - for 2014-09-28 it returns 39 (and it's correct! - http://weeknumber.net/?q=2014-09-28), while Tomalak's answer returns 40.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the [DATEPART mssql function](http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/da-db_8.htm) should help you out with ...

```
DATEPART(wk, ‘Jan 1, xxxx’) = 1
```

Well I'll be.. turns out there is a way to set the first day of the week, [DATEFIRST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx)

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- for monday
```

**Update**: Now I understand better, what the OP wants.. which is custom-logic for this. I don't think MSSQL would have functions with such rich level of customization. But I may be wrong... I think you'll have to roll your own UDF here...sorry

Comment: No, Hojou is looking for the ISO Week Number (ISO 8601). That has to be solved with a UDF.

Answer (score 2):

FORGET THE OTHER ANSWERS

The question specifies "**the week starts monday and week 1 is the first week of the year with atleast 4 days.**" This is **ISO 8601 standard** and what this answer provides. This function is used in production on our site.

This is all you need:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ISOweek  (@DATE DATETIME)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (datepart(DY, datediff(d, 0, @DATE) / 7 * 7 + 3)+6) / 7
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return you the week number of date entered in quotes

```
SELECT DATEPART( wk, 'enter the date over here' )
```

Comment: This will not guarantee ISO 8601 standard as the question specifies

Answer (score 0):

Looks like datepart will get you part of the way there, but you'll have to adjust to get your correct week number, based on the day of week of Jan 1 of the given year.  I'm not familiar enough with T-SQL to do that, but it should be possible.  Pity there isn't a mode argument as in [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)

Answer (score 0):

have you considered using the WEEK function?

This will get you the week of the year for the specified date that you pass in.

```
SELECT { fn WEEK(GETDATE()) } AS WeekNumber, { fn WEEK(CONVERT(DATETIME, '2008-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) } AS FirstWeekOfYear, { fn WEEK(CONVERT(DATETIME, '2008-12-31 00:00:00', 102)) } AS LastWeekOfYear
```

This outputs the following  SQL2000 and SQL2005:

- WeekNumber: 50
- FirstWeekOfYear: 1
- LastWeekOfYear: 53

I Hope this helps :)

Comment: It looks like it has the same problem DatePart(wk, getdate()) and will not work. SELECT { fn WEEK('2003-12-31') } AS WeekNumber gives me 53 which is wrong, since the correct week number is 1

Answer (score 0):

Why yet again, people make mountains out of mole-hills, it astounds me?

So simple...

```
select DATEPART(wk, GETDATE())
```

Comment: This will not guarantee ISO 8601 standard as the question specifies

Comment: but at least it's a starting point and they can play with their own Culture settings.

Comment: @Kleky, incorrect. The OP did not mention anything about an ISO standard

Comment: "Also where i come from, the week starts monday and week 1 is the first week of the year with at least 4 days." = ISO standard