# Getting dates based on week number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have some rows in my database that contains some dates.

I need to select all dates based on a weeknumber, how is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The T-SQL `DATEPART` function will take `week` (abbreviated form `wk`) as its first parameter. This will do what you want. Reference here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Comment: This helped me getting the right week number: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348880/getting-week-number-off-a-date-in-ms-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 0):

```
select date from table_name where DATE_FORMAT(date, "%U-%Y")="11-2010"
```

where 11 is week number

and 2010 is year