# PHP/MsSQL find week of the year in database results

Tags: php, sql-server

I am currently using the query below to collect a total of the ER_read table in between 2 dates. This works fine but I need to split these results into weekly segments e.g. the first week of october = 40 (i think). Is there a function in MsSQL or PHP to do this, and how would I use it?

```
  SELECT SUM(ER_read) as total
    FROM tblEread
   WHERE ER_ID='$sensor'
     AND MONTH(ER_date) >= '$firstMonth'
     AND MONTH(ER_date) <= '$lastMonth'
     AND YEAR(ER_date) = '$year'
GROUP BY ER_ID;
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following tagging from mySQL to MSSQL, see here:

[Getting week number off a date in MS SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348880/getting-week-number-off-a-date-in-ms-sql-server-2005)

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=week+number+sql+server

> select (datepart(dd,'2008-10-08')-1) / 7 + 1

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've tried using WEEK() and WEEKOFYEAR() but I just get a message saying that those functions don't exist..are they only in MySQL? After some googling I've found a function DATEPART which seems to work so far

Comment: See here, if you havent already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348880/getting-week-number-off-a-date-in-ms-sql-server-2005

Comment: Apparently they are. Please tag your question **only** with the database language you are using instead of trying to drum up support for your question with irrelevant tags. Then you won't have this problem.