# What's the name of this week number algorithm?

Tags: date, language-agnostic

My customer wants to display week numbers as they show up in his wall calendar:

1. Week #1 starts on 1st January
2. Last week of the year (#53 or #54) ends on 31st December
3. All other weeks start on Monday and end on Sunday

(As a consequence, first and last weeks do not necessarily have 7 days.)

Does this week number algorithm have a name?

**Clarification:** I already have PHP code to calculate it, I'm just curious about whether this way of identifying weeks has a commonly accepted name.

Comment: Because that won't help me when looking for information and it won't help other programmers that'll see the code later.

Comment: Ok, how about `week number calculator`: http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/weekcalc.htm

Comment: One more for help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274861/how-do-i-calculate-the-week-number-given-a-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't one - that is a completely off-the-wall approach to week numbers.  Weeks normally start either with Monday or Sunday when using the Gregorian Calendar.  They do not start midway.  This is not a criticism of your customer, but a comment on the fact that people invent new ways looking at date arithmetic.  And get in trouble migrating to new systems.

RFC 3339

```
http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt
```

See also ISO 8601