# How to get first day of week in c

Tags: c, time, calendar

I am coding little calendar program in c.
I have issue to get first day of week in current locale, i need it to format calendar. For example Sunday - is first day of week in US, but in Europe first day of week is Monday. How can i get this information for current locale? Thank you.

Comment: Try to understand the history and compilers.

Comment: C itself has no concept of locale; that is provided (differently) by the various environments you may be using, such as POSIX or Windows.  (C++ does have some built-in notion of locale.)

Comment: @Kos: i mean: http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/GCC

Comment: @YumYumYum I fail to see how that's useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine which day is the first in week in current locale in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409902/how-to-determine-which-day-is-the-first-in-week-in-current-locale-in-c)

Comment: @bažmegakapa I got it. I removed my answer as I linked the duplicate question as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a config file containing a map of locale and first day of the week. Read this config file and create a look up table at the beginning of the program. Refer to this table everytime you are trying to get the first day of the week for a particular locale.