# Getting day week starts

Tags: c++, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine what day of week the week starts with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351196/determine-what-day-of-week-the-week-starts-with)
>   [How to determine which day is the first in week in current locale in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409902/how-to-determine-which-day-is-the-first-in-week-in-current-locale-in-c)

How to get parameter which can show from what day week starts using user location date time settings?
e.g. USA: the week starts with Sunday, for Russia it is Monday.

Comment: Which operating system? C++ (the language) has no facilities for this.

Comment: Try boost::locale: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/locale/doc/html/dates_times_timezones.html

Comment: I don't think it's really a duplicate since those questions were about C, while this one is about C++.

Comment: @MichałGórny: Sure, but any solution for C will also work for C++.

Comment: @Oliver so i need to use an other library, in the standart one there are no tools? Ok, i`ll try

Comment: @GregHewgill: yet there are C++ solutions which won't work for C, and you can't expect such a solutions on the C questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain it using one of the following libraries:

1. [boost.locale](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/locale/doc/html/classboost_1_1locale_1_1calendar.html#a8144b98a316798476040348483fe2a6e),
2. [icu](http://userguide.icu-project.org/datetime/calendar),
3. and finally, [glibc has a function for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409902/how-to-determine-which-day-is-the-first-in-week-in-current-locale-in-c/11410437#11410437) too (but it's plain C, not C++ and not really portable).