# How Get Start Day of Week?

Tags: c++, date

I have adjusted the first day of week at Region and Local settings in a control panel (Windows 7), and now I'm writing a C++ function that must returns the first day of week which I have adjusted. 
Any Windows API or standard c++ function that I can use it ?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: "the first day of week which selected": can't understand that fragment. Give an example.

Comment: This seems to bee a question that Google will gladly give you an answer for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine what day of week the week starts with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351196/determine-what-day-of-week-the-week-starts-with)

Comment: I need get a start day of week that selected at Region and Local settings in a control panel (Windows  OS)

Comment: Look at this ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try use a GetLocaleInfoEx windows API and it worked well :)

```
int GetSystemStartDayOfWeek()
{
    int   ret;
    DWORD StartDayOfWeek;

    ret = GetLocaleInfoEx(LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT,
        LOCALE_IFIRSTDAYOFWEEK | LOCALE_RETURN_NUMBER,
        (LPTSTR)&StartDayOfWeek,
        sizeof(StartDayOfWeek) / sizeof(TCHAR));

    return StartDayOfWeek;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

(Sorry what I had written was totally wrong. I have updated the post.)

The right function to use is [EnumCalendarInfoExEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317805(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

BOOL CALLBACK EnumCalendarInfoProcExEx(LPWSTR lpszInfo, CALID calendar, LPWSTR lpReserved, LPARAM lParam)
{
    StringCchCopy(reinterpret_cast<LPWSTR>(lParam), 64, lpszInfo);
    return FALSE;
}

int main()
{
    WCHAR szDay[64];
    BOOL bResult = ::EnumCalendarInfoExEx(
        &EnumCalendarInfoProcExEx,
        LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT,
        ENUM_ALL_CALENDARS,
        nullptr,
        CAL_SDAYNAME1,
        reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(szDay)
        );

    if (!bResult)
    {
        wcout << L"Error" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    wcout << szDay << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

A couple of things to watch out for:

- Even though the first day of the week is configured as Sunday in Control Panel on my PC, this returns Monday...
- Apparently there can be multiple calendars for the user's locale. The above code only gets the first day for the first calendar.

Comment: I try modification to tour code as use a GetLocaleInfoEx that returns a CALID "Caleder ID" and pass it as replacement to  CAL_SDAYNAME1 parameter in main function, but the result has tow issues:
1- Always the start day returned a previous day for example if the first day is Sunday the result is Saturday.
2- The result returned as string how can I get it as integer.
thanks.