# I need to get the weekofyear for the current date in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I believe I have done my due diligence in attempting to find the answer to this.  How do you get the weekofyear in Inno Setup? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Inno doesn't do much with date handling beyond "Get the current date/time as a string". Depending on what you need, it may be easier to move out to an external DLL and call that.

Answer (score 0):

WeekOfYear is not a supported function within InnoSetup.  There is no reference to it within the source code.  You will need to write your own implementation.  While this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274861/how-do-i-calculate-the-week-number-given-a-date) is geared toward C++, it has a pseudocode algorithm you can use to implement it within the Inno Pascal Script.