# Check if timestamp falls in current week in perl

Tags: perl

I have a hash containing keys and timestamps as values as shown below. Is there a way to find which keys have current week's timestamp.

```
my %hash = (
      'key1'  => '2018-01-17',
      'key2'  => '2018-02-05,2018-01-08',
      'key3'  => '2018-01-26' ,
      'key4'  => '2018-01-04',
      'key5'  => '2018-01-27,2018-02-06,2018-01-28'
    );
```

Expected result is : 'key2' and 'key5' with values 2018-02-05 and 2018-02-06 falling in current week.

Comment: Do you prefer "use module X" solution or "use raw perl" solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974992/find-week-of-a-year-given-the-date-in-mm-dd-yyyy

Comment: modules solution is fine. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean calendar week, and which day do you start the week on? Or do you mean 'within the last 7 days'?

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you having trouble with looping over the keys/dates, or testing a date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I like [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) for all my date/time needs because it is a pretty complete solution. In the following, I've assumed that your hash's values are consistently formatted (`YYYY-MM-DD` separated by commas, no whitespace). Also note that this uses Monday as the first day of the week, see the [DateTime truncate method](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#$dt-%3Etruncate(-to-=%3E-...-)) for details.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my %hash = (
    'key1' => '2018-01-17',
    'key2' => '2018-02-05,2018-01-08',
    'key3' => '2018-01-26',
    'key4' => '2018-01-04',
    'key5' => '2018-01-27,2018-02-06,2018-01-28'
);

my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new( on_error=>'croak',
    pattern => '%Y-%m-%d', time_zone=>'floating' );

my $week_start = DateTime->now(time_zone=>'local')
    ->set_time_zone('floating')->truncate(to=>'week');
my $week_end   = $week_start->clone->add( days => 7 );

for my $key (sort keys %hash) {
    for my $date (split /,/, $hash{$key}) {
        my $dt = $strp->parse_datetime($date);
        # DateTime objects overload comparison operators
        if ( $week_start <= $dt && $dt < $week_end ) {
            print "$key\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't truncate unless you switch to floating, or it can [fail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18489927/589924). Fixed.

Comment: @ikegami - Thanks, though it's `floating` and not `float`, fixed. Update: Ah, seems we both caught that at almost exactly the same time :-)

Comment: @ikegami - Hm, yes, using `local` time is probably better, edited, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of ways of doing what you want. With [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) which I believe is core as of Perl 5.9.5, you could do:

```
use Time::Piece;

my %hash = (
  'key1' => '2018-01-17',
  'key2' => '2018-02-05,2018-01-08',
  'key3' => '2018-01-26' ,
  'key4' => '2018-01-04',
  'key5' => '2018-01-27,2018-02-06,2018-01-28'
);

my $current = localtime->strftime('%Y-%V');

foreach my $i (sort keys %hash) {
  foreach my $j (split /\s*,\s*/, $hash{$i}) {
    if( localtime->strptime($j, '%Y-%m-%d')->strftime('%Y-%V') eq $current ) {
      print 'Key: ', $i, ', date: ', $j, "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

It uses the fact that `%V` is the ISO 8601 week number, which concatenated with the year gives something to compare against.

The function `strptime` turns strings into date-objects and then `strftime` turns date-objects into strings.

The output:

```
Key: key2, date: 2018-02-05
Key: key5, date: 2018-02-06
```

The function `strftime` has other week definitions which you may use: `%U`, `%V` and `%W`; see for instance [here](http://search.cpan.org/~dexter/POSIX-strftime-GNU-0.02/lib/POSIX/strftime/GNU.pm).

Comment: You were comparing the week of a local date with the week of a UTC date. That could lead to weird (i.e. incorrect) results. Fixed.

Comment: @ikegami, you have edited the code so it only remains to thank you!

Comment: Thankyou ikegami, Javier and haukex for the explanation and code sample. Working wonderfully!