# Perl: Getting weeknumbers from pre-formatted date-time strings

Tags: date, perl

I am getting date-time strings in the format "2021-04-25 04:27:35" (YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss) and need to convert them to "2021w18".
I must get the weeknumber and I already have the below in my perl script.

```
use Time::Piece;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
```

*Any help will help me progress beyond "newbie".*

Comment: Where on earth (or elsewhere) is the week of 2021-04-25 the 18th?

Comment: _..I already have the below in my perl script_. Your code is not evaluating anything apart from loading the above two Perl libraries/modules. First you must understand what does [use](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use) does.

Comment: Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974992/find-week-of-a-year-given-the-date-in-mm-dd-yyyy) could help you to get the right result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a subroutine that will do what you want:

```perl
use Time::Piece;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
sub dateToWeek {
    my ($date) = @_;
    my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
    return $t->strftime("%Yw%U");
}
say dateToWeek("2021-04-25 04:27:35");
```

Output:

```
2021w17
```

Pass it a date contained in a string and it will return the year + "w" + week number.
If you need it to return 2021w18 instead of 2021w17 for April 25, 2021, change the return statement to add 1 to the strftime like so:

```
return $t->year . "w" . ($t->strftime("%U")+1);
```

Comment: Rather than `$t->year . "w" . $t->strftime("%U")` (which looks rather complicated), you could just use `$t->strftime("%Yw%U")`.