# How to find out the date of the first day of week from the week number in C++

Tags: c++, math, time, dayofweek, jquery-week-calendar

Need a C++ function to find out the date of the first day of week from the week number.

Input : year and week number
Output : date [It should be 1st day of that week number]

e.g :

- inputs :

  - year – `2017`, week number – `8`
    Output: `20th Feb 2017`
- inputs:

  - year – `2017`, week number – `10`
    Output: `6th March 2017

Comment: Your wish is unlikely to be fulfilled if you do not show what you have tried so far. Post your code.

Comment: is there any standard function that can give me date from week number? otherwise, i will need to take today's date and week and go back/forward to get date i want of week number..

Comment: There are clues from going the other way here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274861/how-do-i-calculate-the-week-number-given-a-date

Comment: No, there is "standard function" that does this. This is what you need to do: take out a piece of paper, and a pen; then write down in short, logical sentences, a step by step process to implement this calculation. Once you have done so, [take this piece of paper to your rubber duck, for a review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Once your rubber duck approves your proposed algorithm, simply take what you've written down, and translate it directly into C++. You're done.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source, header-only date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date), it can look like this:

```
#include "date.h"
#include "iso_week.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace iso_week::literals;
    std::cout << date::year_month_day{2017_y/8_w/mon} << '\n';
    std::cout << date::year_month_day{2017_y/10_w/mon} << '\n';
}
```

which outputs:

```
2017-02-20
2017-03-06
```

There are also getters for year, month and day on the `year_month_day` types, and plenty of formatting options.

Comment: Thanks for the reply:) But i am not able to add these files in VS10 - getting error can not open date.h & iso_week.h

Comment: @user2991556: This is a 3rd party library (I'm principle author) located on GitHub.  You have to click on the blue-colored link in the first sentence of my answer above.  That being said, VS10 is too antiquated to work with this library.  It lacks `<chrono>` altogether, which this library is built upon.  This library requires VS13 or later.