# How to get week of year in SQL with calendar rule?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, calendar

In .NET C# there is the Calendar.GetWeekOfYear Method

```
public virtual int GetWeekOfYear(
DateTime time,
CalendarWeekRule rule,
DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek)
```

where there is a parameter "CalendarWeekRule" to define the rules.
In my case, I used CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek to assert that a week needs to have 4 days in the same month to be considered a week.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear(v=vs.110).aspx

How can I do this in SQL?
Is there an equivalent function?

Comment: FYI: ISO 8601 defines weeks of the year, and uses Monday as day 1 of the week, and stipulates that the week must have at least 4 days in the year it belongs to (so if 1st January falls on Mon-Thu, it belongs to the current year, but if it falls on Fri-Sun, it is part of the last week of the previous year, and it might be week 52 or week 53 of the previous year.  Fundamentally, you have to get the 'day of year' value (1 for 1st January, 365 or 366 for 31st December), and also the 'day of week' of 1st January in the year, and dink around with arithmetic.

Comment: Note [How do I calculate the week number given a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274861/how-do-i-calculate-the-week-number-given-a-date/275024#275024)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you. Is there an option to use Sunday as day 1 of the week instead of Monday?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DATEPART ( wk, date )
```

This will return an integer for the week from the date you provide. For further parameters of `DATEPART` here is the link! [DATEPART TSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql)

EDIT : As you asked in the comments for your question, you can change the first day of the week with `SET DATEFIRST =` [(see values here)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql)

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful

Comment: sql server uses the .net equivalent of System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, If table is 'tblWeekOfYear' and [time] is a DateTime field, then it calculates the week no of the two different dates `'2017-10-01' and '2017-10-02'` in the DateTime field.

```
Select Distinct DatePart(ww, [time]) as WeekNo
from tblWeekOfYear where [time] between '2017-10-01' and '2017-10-02';
```