# Hive from_unixtime behaving differently for different dates

Tags: datetime, hadoop, hive

I am trying to get week number for a given date. But its working for few dates and not working for couple of dates.

Followed this link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
 select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2015-12-31','yyyy-MM-dd'),'w') week_in_year;
```

The above code is returning 1

```
 select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2016-12-31','yyyy-MM-dd'),'w') week_in_year;
```

The above code is returning 53. I think the first code snippet also should give something like 53/52. Any help is appreciated in solving.

Comment: Both are plausibly correct.  ISO 8601 lays down the rules.  You can find a lot of information in my answer to [How do I calculate the week number given a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274861/how-do-i-calculate-the-week-number-given-a-date/275024?s=2|58.0167#275024)

Comment: If your question is: "Which week does 2015-12-31 fall in?" then my answer, based on 'day 1 is Monday', is 2015-12-31 = 2015-W53 = 2015-W53-4.  For 2016-12-31, my answer is 2016-12-31 = 2016-W52 = 2016-W52-6.  I would have to work harder to make the code work with '1st day of week is Sunday'.

Comment: I observe that 2015-12-31 was Thursday (day 4); 2016-12-31 was Saturday (day 6) — the Unix `cal` program confirms those observations.